# continuous transition one by one in image gallery

Tags: css

I have three images placed side by side .I want that they continuously keep fading in and out to 50% of their opacity one after another. Only one image is visible at opacity =100% at atime 
the process needs to be automatic after page load. I have tried for hours but with no result.any help would be appreciated.

Comment: post your code so we can see what you've been trying, and we can help you fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my jQuery plugin.It does the same.
https://github.com/raynesax/Super-Slider